# Foreach Powershell command for Sky for Business

Tags: powershell, foreach

I'm creating a report of my users in SFB. To collect information from just one user, it works perfectly, but I need to collect it from everyone so I used the command Get-Content and then foreach to get each line in my user base registered in the users.txt
Could someone help me if this is a syntax error?

Thanks

```
$users = Get-Content C:\temp\skypeproject\users.txt
$list = foreach ( $user in $users ) 
{ 
    Get-CsOnlineUser -Identity $user | Format-table -AutoSize DisplayName, EnterpriseVoiceEnabled,HostedVoiceMail,OnPremLineURI,LineURI 
}
```

[Error Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZ9dv.jpg)

Comment: The error seems to show testing content in the `.txt` file. Check this and remove any testing/fake entries

Comment: I did this, it's the same message

Answer (score 1):

Per the comments, it does seem like you are getting an error because of some bad data in your input file. One way to handle this might be with a `Try..Catch` block, so that when a single user causes you an error it doesn't stop the overall script.

```
$Users = Get-Content C:\temp\skypeproject\users.txt

$List = foreach ( $User in $Users ) { 
    Try {
        Get-CsOnlineUser -Identity $user -ErrorAction Stop
    }
    Catch {
        "Error for $User: $_"
    }
}

$List | Format-table -AutoSize DisplayName, EnterpriseVoiceEnabled,HostedVoiceMail,OnPremLineURI,LineURI
```

I've also moved the use of `Format-Table` to outside of your loop, as otherwise your `$List` variable doesn't end up containing an object that could be useful if you needed to do anything else with it.